# Encode part of url in xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm a total newbie in xsl so I'm not even sure this is possible.  This code is for building a menu that does a postback to the same page so that ITEMNMBR can be picked up from the query string and added to a grid when building an order.  There are special characters in some of the item numbers.

I have the following code and need to encode the ITEMNMBR part of this URL so that when the hyperlink is selected, nothing blows up.

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItem">
    <li><a href="OrderEntry.aspx?ITEMNMBR={ITEMNMBR}"><xsl:value-of select="ITEMNMBR"/></a></li>  <!-- Inventory items -->  <!-- need only encode itemnmbr -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Am I headed down the right path with how I'm attempting to do this?  And could someone point me in the right direction as to how to get this encoded?   Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you use `<xsl:output method="html" />` the processor may well handle the necessary escaping automatically.

Comment: I added <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/> to my xsl file and re-ran it through XML Notepad but no dice.  Url still looks the same. I was hoping to use encodeURIComponent() .. thinking that would work, but I don't know how to implement that in this situation.  Any ideas?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has an `encode-for-uri` function but I don't know of a standard function you can use if you're stuck with 1.0. There are various processor-specific extensions but nothing in the standard, though I wouldn't be surprised if someone can point you to an implementation of uri encoding as a callable template, the question has definitely come up before.

Comment: Thanks to you too Ian for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you could use **encode-for-uri** directly

```
<a href="OrderEntry.aspx?ITEMNMBR={encode-for-uri(ITEMNMBR)}">
```

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you could do it with some form of extension function but that would depend on what platform you were using. If you were using Mircosoft technology, that provides the **[msxsl:script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx)** element which you could use to call JavaScript functions directl. For example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     xmlns:js="madeup.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl js">

   <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="js">
   function uriencode(string) 
   {
      return encodeURIComponent(string);
   } 
   </msxsl:script>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="MenuItem">
         <li>
            <a href="OrderEntry.aspx?ITEMNMBR={js:uriencode(string(ITEMNMBR))}">
               <xsl:value-of select="ITEMNMBR"/>
            </a>
         </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am indeed using MS technology. This is a .NET Webforms app (I should have mentioned that).  I bet one of these things will fix it.  I'm off to try it and see how it goes.  Thanks for your help and I will definitely mark this as answer if I can get it working right.

Comment: The MS side of this answer fixed it for me.  Thanks very much!  I am using the .NET framework 4.0 which (from what I can tell) does not yet support XLST 2.0 .. let me know if I'm wrong on that though. Thanks again Tim!

Comment: You are not wrong on that, alas. Microsoft has no love for XSLT 2.0.

Comment: There are of course at least two XSLT 2.0 processors available for .NET - Saxon and XmlPrime - and since they are both under active development whereas Microsoft haven't done anything new in the XML world for years, you ought to consider moving forward.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about those.  I will look into them and how to add them to .NET project.  Thanks again!